# How to make a proper pagination with Vuejs? Setter not defined error

Tags: vue.js, pagination, computed-properties

Working on the pageNav for a personal app I am working on and cannot get the index to show properly.

I figure that making the `pageIndexInner` and `itemsPerPageInner` computed propetries was the best route, but when it comes to editing those, I need to also have a setter? I've looked into getters and setters, but am having a very hard time wrapping my head around it.

Without the computer properties, the click event works and I can make it all the way to the `itemToal` amount, but the index doesn't match up.

If you change the default pageIndex to 3,
I want to see:

[image]

but this is what I'm actually seeing:

[image]

I'm just not sure where to go with all of this and any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Codepen Link:https://codepen.io/LovelyAndy/pen/NWbjLGz?editors=1010

Vue Component code:

```
<template>
    <div class="_table-page-nav-wrapper">
    <div @click="back" :disabled="pageIndexInner === 0" class="_arrow-btn">
    <
    </div>
    <div class="_page-index-inner">
      {{ itemsTotal }} Total Items {{ pageIndexInnerStart}} - {{ itemsPerPageInnerStart }} Shown
    </div>
    
    <div @click="forward" class="_arrow-btn">
  >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
._table-page-nav-wrapper
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  div
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center

._arrow-btn
  width: 50px
  height: 50px
  border-radius: 4px
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)

._page-index-inner
  width: 244px
  height: 50px
  border-radius: 4px
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
  margin: 0px 20px
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TablePageNavigation',
  props: {
    /**
     * passed values can be either 10 or 25 or 50
     */
    itemsPerPage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 10,
      validator: (prop) => [10, 25, 50].includes(prop),
    },
    pageIndex: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    itemsTotal: {
      type: Number,
      default: 100,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pageIndexInner: this.pageIndex,
      itemsPerPageInner: this.itemsPerPage,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pageIndexInnerStart() {
      return this.pageIndex + this.itemsPerPage
    },
    itemsPerPageInnerStart() {
      return this.itemsPerPage + this.itemsPerPage
    },
  },
  methods: {
    back() {
      if (this.itemsPerPageInner > this.itemsPerPage) {
        this.itemsPerPageInner = this.itemsPerPageInner - this.itemsPerPage
        this.pageIndexInner = this.pageIndexInner - this.itemsPerPage
        const newIndex = this.pageIndexInner
        this.$emit('update:pageIndex', newIndex)
      }
      return
    },
    forward() {
      if (
        this.itemsPerPageInnerStart + this.itemsPerPage > this.itemsTotal ||
        this.PageIndexInnerStart + this.itemsPerPage > this.itemsTotal
      ) {
        return
      }
      this.pageIndexInnerStart = this.pageIndexInnerStart + this.itemsPerPage
      this.itemsPerPageInnerStart = this.itemsPerPageInnerStart + this.itemsPerPage
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented on your related question earlier this morning, and decided to create an example based on my previous pagination implementation that I mentioned.  I removed a lot of your calculations for a simpler approach. I didn't handle all scenarios such as if total items is not a multiple of items per page, but if you like what I did you can work that out on your own.  Here is the code from my single file component that I developed in my Vue sandbox app, which uses Bootstrap 4.

```
<template>
  <div class="table-page-navigation">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="back" >Back</button>

    <span>
      {{ itemsTotal }} Total Items {{ pageFirstItem}} - {{ pageLastItem }} Shown
    </span>

    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="forward" >Forward</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TablePageNavigation',
    props: {
      /**
       * passed values can be either 10 or 25 or 50
       */
      itemsPerPage: {
        type: Number,
        default: 10,
        validator: (prop) => [10, 25, 50].includes(prop),
      },
      itemsTotal: {
        type: Number,
        default: 100,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        currentPage: 1,
      }
    },
    computed: {
      numPages() {
        return this.itemsTotal / this.itemsPerPage;
      },
      pageFirstItem() {
        return (this.currentPage - 1) * this.itemsPerPage + 1;
      },
      pageLastItem() {
        return this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      back() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1) {
          this.currentPage--;
        }
      },
      forward() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.numPages) {
          this.currentPage++;
        }
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)

[Vuetify pagination Component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/#usage)

This might help if you're comfortable using a UI library.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <div class="text-center">
          <v-pagination
            v-model="page"
            :length="6"
          ></v-pagination>
        </div>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data () {
      return {
        page: 1,
      }
    },
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was actually looking into Vuetify for some practice with a UI framework. This is a bit tangential to my question, but do you recommend Vuetify over other UI frameworks? or is this just the one you used for this particular issue? Cheers!

Comment: Personally, I'm a big fan of Vue and Vuetify both. I highly recommend Vuetify over any other UI library for Vue.